# Yandex.Maps API получить существующую карту в переменную

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

В одном скрипте я создаю карту:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        ymaps.ready(init);
        var myMap;
        function init() {
            myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                center: [55.76, 37.64],
                zoom: 7
            });
        }
    </script>
```

А в другом скрипте мне нужно нарисовать метку на ней:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function addPlacemark() {
    var myMap,
            myPlacemark;
    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.76, 37.64], {
        hintContent: 'Москва!',
        balloonContent: 'Столица России'
    });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
}
        </script>
```

Как во втором скрипте, который ничего не знает о существующей карте, засунуть ее в переменную `myMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявите `myMap` там где его будет видно из обоих скриптов. Собственно, если бы вы его не переопределяли заново (`var myMap;` переопределяет myMap) во втором скрипте, то оба скрипта работали бы с одним и тем же `myMap`. Помните, что область видимости переменной, определенной через `var` - это все тело функции, где она определена.